# How to get Exception details without debugger?

Tags: c#, .net

I'm testing a .net 4 application on a stock windows install and get a crash as it starts up. 
The "View problem details" from the error dialog tells me that its a System.IO.FileNotFoundException but does not show the exception data so I have no idea what file it's trying to load.

Is there a way to get some more detailed data about the exception without installing visual studio?

Comment: Your problem looks like a missing library/dependency issue. If that's the case, the framework might have dumped the exception details to the windows event log. Have a look there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write an event handler for AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException.  Log or display the value of e.ExceptionObject.ToString() to get the exception message and the stack trace.

Comment: I've tried all the suggestions above but ProcMon was very verbose and I couldn't pinpoint what failed loading, while the system log yielded very little additional information and did not identify the missing file. Hooking top level exceptions and logging them was definitely the easiest option.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [ProcMon](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-en/sysinternals/bb896645) to Monitor your application to find out wich file it tries to find.
(When starting Procmon you should filter out every thing else before starting your App)

Answer (score 1):

You can also try looking at the Windows Event Log. For example, a quick search on my machine found the following error from MetroTwit (a .NET Twitter client):

```
Application: MetroTwit.exe
Framework Version: v4.0.30319
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
Exception Info: System.InvalidOperationException
Stack:
   at System.Windows.Application.GetResourcePackage(System.Uri)
   at System.Windows.Application.LoadComponent(System.Object, System.Uri)
   at MetroTwit.View.ErrorView.InitializeComponent()
   at MetroTwit.View.ErrorView..ctor(System.String)
   at MetroTwit.App.Application_DispatcherUnhandledException(System.Object,     System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherUnhandledExceptionEventArgs)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.CatchException(System.Exception)
   at MS.Internal.Threading.ExceptionFilterHelper.TryCatchWhen(System.Object,         
    System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32, System.Delegate)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.WrappedInvoke(System.Delegate, System.Object, 
    Int32, System.Delegate)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.InvokeImpl(
    System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority, System.TimeSpan, System.Delegate, 
    System.Object, Int32)
   at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.SubclassWndProc(IntPtr, Int32, IntPtr, IntPtr)
   at MS.Win32.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessage(System.Windows.Interop.MSG ByRef)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrameImpl(
    System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherFrame)
   at System.Windows.Application.RunInternal(System.Windows.Window)
   at System.Windows.Application.Run()
   at MetroTwit.App.Main()
```

The error level was Error and the source was ".NET Runtime"

Comment: It *is* automatic and very useful too.

Comment: It is automatic, but most of the details of the exception are not logged. However you want just a stack trace this is definitely a quick and easy way!